# Cant able to Delete Row from sqlite Database

Tags: iphone

Can any one help me what he Problem in Code. I cant able to delete Row from the Database.

```
-(void) deleteData {

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSString *destinationPath = [self getDestinationPath];

    const char *dbpath = [destinationPath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {


        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM BirthdayListDB WHERE id=\"%@\"",details.ids];

        const char *insert_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Row deleted");

        } 

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to delete row");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

}
```

Here (sqlite3_stmt    *statement;) i am not getting statement value. I am getting null value for statement.Can any 1 help me in solving this.

Thanks!

Comment: IF any answer if helpful to you than please accept it. So Any other user can know the correct or useful answer

Answer (score 3):

Just Replace

```
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM BirthdayListDB WHERE id=\"%@\"",details.ids];
```

With

```
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM BirthdayListDB WHERE id='%@'",details.ids];
```

Thanks,